# How to preserve new lines with xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, php

I'm testing out sending data to a php script from a text box in javascript with xmlhttp:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "testphp.php?q=" + str, true);
```

str is the value of a textbox which contains character returns. When the data comes back from testphp.php (which just echos the string), the new lines disappear and it's just one blob of text.

How can I preserve the character returns?

Comment: How are you ouputting the info and what element are you adding it to.

Comment: you're viewing the text in an html context, and html does NOT honor newlines in the text. you need to wrap it in `<pre>` tags or equivalent CSS, or use php's `nl2br()` to do `\n` -> `<br>` conversions.

Comment: I'm just testing the output in an alert for now. When I alert the result before the xmlhttp there are new lines, but when it comes back they dissapear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "testphp.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(str), true);
```

In the testphp.php

```
<?=isset($_GET['q'])?'<pre>'.$_GET['q'].'</pre>':''?>
```

Comment: I just had to use the xmlhttp code you gave, the php didn't need to be changed and it works great, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `white-space:pre-wrap` on whatever element contains your output data.

Example: [[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lb5E/)]

```
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap">Whee!

      Look at me, I have space!

    Space? Space! SPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACE!</div>
```

Comment: he fell in a pit or just excited?

Comment: @Sharky Ba! Ba-ba! Ba ba ba ba!

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to see the new lines in my alert though? There are new lines in the alert before I send, when it comes back they dissapear.

Comment: Depends how you're getting it in your alert in the first place. Show code?

Comment: It's just alerting xmlhttp.responseText. Nevermind though user3493274's answer worked well for me, thanks.